# How do you decrease the score on a scoreboard? (Minecraft)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I decrease a score on the scoreboard? I tried

```
/scoreboard players minus @a score 1
```

and also

```
/scoreboard players subtract @a score 1
```

but they don't seem to work. How do I do this?

Comment: Next time, type "/scoreboard players" and then click tab a few times to scroll thru possible next words until you find a phrase that seems like it might work.

Answer (score 3):

You use

```
/scoreboard players remove @a score 1
```